# Would there be benefit in CakePHP performance if it dropped support for JS/AJAX engines?

Tags: php, performance, cakephp

My main Question:

**Is there any practical effect on performance of CakePHP (i.e. faster view rendering), if support for JS helpers was dropped from the core completely?**

My reasoning:

Right now CakePHP has a few classes that allow a programmer to create basic client-side code using PHP, both for things like effects and AJAX requests.

There is some coupling with the View object, which could be degrading to performance.

Considering that a lot of frameworks are moving to a RESTful model and in general it is hard to keep up with the changes of the client-side frameworks, while coupling them with the server-side framework, like CakePHP.

I am wondering if it's worthwhile to drop support for JS/AJAX and focus on PHP framework patterns. Of course we lose the ability to write some JS code through the helpers, but in my opinion it is still best left to a JS framework.

The benefits are reduced coupling, lighter weight, and possibly improved performance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JsHelper is going to be removed from core in 3.0 anyway :)  I doubt there be any major performance enhancement. The main reason behind the decision is the php wrapper functions to generated js code have very limited functionality and sooner or later you will find out its gets in your way rather than speeding up development. So it's decided to remove the JsHelper and reduce the code to maintain.

Comment: More info [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/cakephp-core/UaXqk_rTdxE). teknoid I wish an experienced user like you could take more active interest in CakePHP development :)

Comment: although it doesn't answer my question directly, it is clearly what i was wondering in the long run... and it does remind me to stay more involved with the cake community :)

Comment: I did address your main question, kind of. Personally I am not too sure of any significant speed up of view rendering. Not sure what coupling in View object you are referring to. Afaik only the PaginatorHelper uses the JsHelper.

Edit: Ah and FormHelper too.

Comment: @admad just found this post via your profile. I agree on removing the JsHelper. Apart from Js->buffer(), I don't use it's functionality anyway). However, would it be a good idea to mention this in CakeBook? "This helper will be removed in 3.0, use ViewBlocks in stead and don't rely on the other methods for new projects?"

Comment: @thaJeztah 3.0 is still a fair way away even for development release. So it would be premature to add the info into manual right now. 3.0 is not going to be fully backwards compatible with 2.x anyway. Also even though it's removed from core it might be available as a separate plugin.

Comment: @Admad good to know (about the plugin), however, I'll try not to advice users to rely on the javascript-generation of the JsHelper too much (coding your javascript by hand may produce better code anyway) :)